# Adding group in Legend in QGIS Map composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, ubuntu

There is a Map composer with created map. I want to "Add group" to Legend - it appears in the Legend Properties, but not in Legend on the map.

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.18.8. This problem was also in 2.16 version. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

You can just **drag and drop** your layers into groups, than just refresh legend item by clicking itnto print composer canvas or any map item.

[image]

Comment: Ok, this feature I have missed and it looks good. But I have some Text labels (like - A, B, C) on map, which want to add to Legend. Trough "Add group" in some previous versions it was dead easy.

Comment: @Oskars sorry I don't understant very well what you want to achieve, maybe you can edit this question, or ask new question with this problem, providing some screenshots or pictures etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `Group` will not be shown until you drag any of the layers inside the new group:

Before adding anything inside the group:

[image]

After drag anything inside the group:

[image]